# ActiveForm without model yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I want to create `ActiveForm` without model for just in case something. I did try with `dynamicModel` but i got some error :

```
use yii\base\DynamicModel;
$model = DynamicModel::validateData(compact('KOMENTAR'), [
   [['KOMENTAR'], 'string', 'max' => 128],
]);
```

This is the form i want to create

```
<br>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'method' => 'post',
]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'KOMENTAR')->textarea(['rows' => 6])->label(false) ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('POST', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>
```

This is the error

```
Getting unknown property: yii\base\DynamicModel::KOMENTAR
```

Comment: you define public $KOMENTAR in your model page

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you are using `compact('KOMENTAR')`, you should have a `$KOMENTAR` variable.

Read more about `compact` : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.compact.php

Or you should simply create your model like this :

```
$model = new \yii\base\DynamicModel(['KOMENTAR']);
$model->addRule(['KOMENTAR'], 'string', ['max' => 128]);
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
    // do what you want 
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Normally **Active**Items are used to work with a model, but Yii2 have a helper class called `Html` to use the same items like classic HTML.

Use [beginForm()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml#beginForm()-detail) method from `Html`. And try something like that:

```
use yii\helpers\Html;

<?= Html::beginForm(['/controller/view', 'id' => $model->id], 'POST'); ?>
<?= Html::textarea('KOMENTAR', '', ['rows' => 6])->label(false); ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('POST', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']); ?>
</div>
<?= Html::endForm(); ?>
```

You can read more about this helper in [the documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-html).

Comment: Do not use BaseHtml. Use yii\helpers\Html instead.

Comment: You are wrong about "Html have more tools for view design", you should read this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-overview.html#customizing-helper-classes

Comment: You should check your Code, there are some synthax errors in it like at `beginForm()([
    'method' => 'post',
])` and `(['rows' => 6, name='KOMENTAR'])`

Comment: It is nice, but does not help me with CKEDITOR 4 + widget for yii2 ( https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget ), when model is absent, so only js helps: `$inputText = Html::textArea('PageData[data]', $data0, ['id'=>'pagedata-data']); echo $inputText; $this->registerJs('CKEDITOR.replace($("textarea#pagedata-data")[0], {})');`